# Отправка текстового файла частями на скачивание (работа с памятью и буфером)

Tags: файлы, php

В общем тема такая:
формируется таблица из базы MySQL.
Результат содержится в переменной, которая представляет из себя массив.

Далее нужно вывести все файлом xml

```
//отправляю заголовки xml
//...........................
    foreach($zzz as $k => $v) {
     echo $v;
    }
```

Код выше, конечно, сложней раз в 100 но суть такая.

Вопрос: как можно отдавать файл частями?
Или такое нельзя?

Ну допустим отправлять к базе кучу запросов и выводить все построчно - это я называю частями, потому что не грузится память.

А как в этом случае можно разгрузить нагрузку???

Надеюсь, Вы меня поняли.

Comment: Помоему это очередная економия на спичках. Сколько отдаваемый контент весить может ?

Comment: Можно делать [flush](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.flush.php) после каждого echo, тогда данные из буфера будут сразу отдаваться браузеру.  
[Здесь]( http://hashcode.ru/questions/93191#93267) другой способ от @Sh4dow

Answer (score 1):

Вообще не проблема. Браузер получает данные по мере того как web-сервер их отдает. Страница считается полностью полученной только после закрытия соединения. На этом принципе основана технология [Comet](http://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=comet&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FComet_(%25D0%25BF%25D1%2580%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B3%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BC%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B8%25D1%2580%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B5)&ei=PCuUUNijDInMswaHm4HYBA&usg=AFQjCNG_uPGtup8_pL2jXMvgpSDysqhnbQ&sig2=n19QNiskqUGp7qgmxLiafA). Но желательно указывать кодировку страницы поскольку иначе браузер буферизирует первые 512 байт для того чтобы попытаться определить кодировку самостоятельно.

Еще буферизировать данные может сам web-сервер, но там обычно буфер небольшой и если цель просто минимизировать расход памяти в php, то на это заморачиваться не стоит.

Да, и echo подходит для этого точно также как любой другой метод вывода.

Comment: соеденение не закрывается ...

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/151795/

Comment: А можно узнать что именно вы, оба-двое, хотели сказать ?

Answer (score 0):

Сильно вряд ли, по крайней мере не `echo` точно)
Тут другой вопрос возникнет: куда Вы выдаете это? Если пользователю в браузер, то нет, браузер получает готовую страницу.
Если куда то в другое место, то смотрите сокеты.